# how to apply Jasypt plugin in grails 2.3.7

Tags: grails, grails-orm, jasypt

I am trying to apply Jasypt plugin in my application to encrypt fields of my table.
here's my code below.

DOMAIN CLASS

```
import com.bloomhealthco.jasypt.GormEncryptedStringType;

class TestForm {

    String name
    String age
    String gender
    static mapping = {
        name type: GormEncryptedStringType
        age type: GormEncryptedStringType
        gender type: GormEncryptedStringType
    }
    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

BUILDCONFIG

```
plugins {
    // plugins for the build system only
    build ":tomcat:7.0.52.1"

    // plugins for the compile step
    compile ":scaffolding:2.0.2"
    compile ':cache:1.1.1'
    compile ":jasypt-encryption:1.2.1"
    // plugins needed at runtime but not for compilation
    runtime ":hibernate:3.6.10.9"  //or ":hibernate4:4.3.4"

}
```

CONFIG

```
//Database encryption configuration
Jasypt {
    algorithm = "PBEWITHSHA256AND256BITAES-CBC-BC"
    providerName = "BC"
    password = "c3kr37"
    keyObtentionIterations = 1000
}
```

all those i have done in my application, This also successfully downloads jasypt plugin. but when i try to save record it show the following error

```
Error 500: Internal Server Error

URI:

/grailsTest/testForm/save

Class:

org.jasypt.exceptions.EncryptionInitializationException

Message:

No string encryptor registered for hibernate with name "gormEncryptor"
```

Hope for the right direction to use this plugin, Thanks in advance.